# error in syntax regarding if statements

Tags: if-statement, syntax

i am very new to programming and am trying to complete my function however i keep getting a syntax error at the semicolon after the first semicolon at the first if statement. what is causing this and how can i remedy it and avoid this error in the future?

```
def guess_who():
          y = random.randint(1,10)
          print("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses")
          for i in range(3):
                a = eval(input('Please enter an interger between 1 and 10:')
                if a < y:
                         print("Your guess is too small.")
                elif a > y:
                         print("Your guess is too big.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ) at the end of the line with eval function.

```
def guess_who():
          y = random.randint(1,10)
          print("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses")
          for i in range(3):
                a = eval(input('Please enter an interger between 1 and 10:'))
                if a < y:
                         print("Your guess is too small.")
                elif a > y:
                         print("Your guess is too big.")
```

Comment: thank you. sadly i realized that after 2 more hours of trying my fuction and rearranging lines.